# sticky for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a problem with a for loop. Most probably it is a silly mistake somewhere that i cant catch. I have a fast enumeration loop that looks like this:

```
for (NSNumber *number in sums) {
    int n = [number intValue];

    NSArray *array = [self getResultForTarget:n];

    for (NSNumber *num in array) {
        NSLog(@"%i",[num intValue]);
    }
}
```

the value for `[num intValue]` is the same for every enumeration of `for (NSNumber *number in sums)` when it is impossible for it to be the same. It is giving the value it calculates in the first enumeration. The method `getResultForTarget:` cannot return the same result for the different (int) arguments it is taking.... what might be going wrong???

p.s. i tried to manually enter the arguments of sums in the method and it returned correct results.

Comment: Can you show us the code for getResultsForTarget?

Comment: ok the code above is not my exact code as i tried to simplify it... ill edit it with the exact thing...

Comment: My concern is that the code in getResultForTarget uses an instance variable at some point and ends up using the same value every iteration when it shouldn't

Comment: i just edited the question with all the methods... it could be a bit complex to understand.. the `getSums:` method is a wrapper for a recursive method that finds all possible sums of a given array of numbers... the `getCombsForNumbers:withTarget:` is also a wrapper for a method that finds the combination of a sum from an array of given numbers (the same numbers)... the 'sticky' method should give the combination of each sum in the `sums` array... I know its probably not an efficient way of doing it but it should work

Comment: @pwny ... your concern was in its place.. i have predefined array im using that was giving the same results.. thanks for the help

Comment: No problem!  Sorry I couldn't take a look at it earlier, I got busy :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it to work... apparently i have an initialized array that should be emptied before each call ...

Answer (score 0):

If you manually entered `sums` and got the right results there is a good chance that the issue is that at run time `sums` does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: i tried logging each value it contains in the for loop.. and they are giving correct values.